# Connect a Centura client application to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, centura

I am new to Centura application configuration

When I try opening the windows client application, which has the Centura `sql.ini` configuration file. I get the below error.

Can anyone please help me understand the issue?

> Error code: 401
>
> Reason: FOR SQLBASE: The specified database cannot be found.  SQLBase cannot find the file named "x:\dbdir\dbname\dbname.DBS" where x:\dbdir is either the default, c:\SQLBASE, or modified with the DBDIR SQL.INI configuration keyword. In a multiuser network configuration, this error indicates that your network is working correctly, but the database system was unable to locate the specified database filename.
>
> FOR NON-SQLBASE DATABASES: This problem can also occur with a SQLGateway when leaving out the protocol type in the SERVERNAME parameter that the client uses to communicate with the gateway (like SQLNBIOS).
>   For example, SERVERNAME=SERVER33,SQLQUEUE DBNAME=DB2DBMS, SQLQUEUE, SQLNBIOS
>
> will not allow a remote client process (using SQLNBIOS on the LAN to communicate with the SQLGateway machine) to connect to the SQLGateway machine.
>
> For SPX connectivity from DOS or MS Windows to a Unixware SQLBase Server check for the omission of the "serverpath=..." parameter in the SQL.INI file under the client section.
>
> Remedy: Verify the database file exists. The default drive letter and dbdirname is c:\SQLBASE unless overridden with a DBDIR SQL.INI configuration keyword parameter. Verify the DBDIR keyword is not missing or pointing to a wrong database directory. Verify the DBNAME keyword is specified for the named database. Verify the SERVER keyword is not missing or conflicting with other network server names. In your CONFIG.SYS file, verify at least 40 files set with the FILES=40 parameter. If the server was being initialized while the connection was tried, retry the connection after the server has initialized.  If all of the above fails, try using a different database name or try connecting to the database in single user mode at the same machine. If you can connect with a local engine it probably indicates a network configuration error exists. If you can connect with a new database name it probably indicates a previously named database was never properly initialized.

Comment: Sql.ini parameters may be not correct

Comment: Yes, thanks you @Chandralal